# C# - Undeclared Prefix in XML

Tags: c#, xml

So I am trying to make a standard xml in C# but receive the error, 'xmii' is an undeclared prefix. I have researched the problem but nothing has seemed to work. Any suggestions?

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<xmii:Request/>");

        docFrag.InnerXml = "<xmii:Name>" + name + "</xmii:Name>";
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(docFrag); 

        docFrag.InnerXml = "<xmii:PWord>" + pword + "</xmii:PWord>";
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(docFrag);
```

Here is an example of what the xml should look like

```html
<xmii:Request>
  <xmii:Name>John</xmii:Name>
  <xmii:PWord>Monkey</xmii:PWord>
</xmii:Request>
```

Comment: You need to add your namespaces to the `XmlDocument`. The xml `<xmii:XacuteRequest/>` is not a complete document and will need an `xmlns:xmii="http://my.namespace.com/xmii/namespace"` attribute at the root.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon thanks for the response. Would I just add the attribute to the initial load of the xml and it would add xmii to the rest of the children? Also, could you give a code example of how I can add an attribute at the root?

Comment: check out this page - it is a pretty good into to XML https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Comment: @MichaelCoxon the problem with the page that you sent me is that it is putting the xmlns into a table and wrapping the rest of the xml within that.  Whereas I need the xml to look like the one I provided in my question. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You can add the namespace on any element - you just need to define it... eg.: `<xmii:XacuteRequest xmlns:xmii="http://my.namespace.com/xmii/namespace"/>`

Comment: Oh ok. Would I add the xmlns:xmii="http://my.namespace.com/xmii/namespace" portion to every node or can I just state xmii:Name and xmii:PWord without adding the namespace again?

Comment: You only need the namespace on the outer element - so that is only on `XacuteRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize the comments. Credit to @MichaelCoxon with his answer. The code works if this is included

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<xmii:Request xmlns:xmii=\"http://my.namespace.com/xmii/namespace\"/>");

        docFrag.InnerXml = "<xmii:Name xmlns:xmii=\"http://my.namespace.com/xmii/namespace\">" + name + "</xmii:Name>";
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(docFrag); 

        docFrag.InnerXml = "<xmii:PWord xmlns:xmii=\"http://my.namespace.com/xmii/namespace\">" + pword + "</xmii:PWord>";
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(docFrag);
```